# Custom css preloader not working for shopify theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify, shopify-template

I am trying to add a custom CSS preloader with the click of an anchor tag in my Shopify theme. The preloader is working fine for windows and android. But it is not responding to iOS devices.
Here is the script and CSS I've used.

```
<div class="loader" id="loader" style="display:none;">
  <div class="lds-ring"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#loader').hide();
jQuery(".startLoader").click(function() {
jQuery('#loader').fadeIn();
});
});
</script> 
<script>
$(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        window.location.reload(); 
    }
});
</script>

CSS:
.loader{background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:999;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;}
.lds-ring {display: inline-block;position: relative;width:120px;height:120px;top:40%;}
.lds-ring div {box-sizing: border-box;display: block;position: absolute;width:100px;height: 100px;margin: 8px;border: 8px solid #CA1F7B;border-radius: 50%;animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
border-color: #CA1F7B transparent transparent transparent;}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {animation-delay: -0.45s;}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: -0.3s;}
.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: -0.15s;}
@keyframes lds-ring {
0% {
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```